# Variance of the sum of random variables, each having a mean of 1?

Tags: probability, expectation, variance, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,...,X_{20}$ be independent Poisson random variables with mean 1. Use the central limit theorem to approximate $$P\{\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i \geq\ 15\}$$.

To solve this question, I need to find the expectation of $X = \sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i $, which I know is equal to 20, but I can't seem to figure out what the variance is.

In the solution manual, they use expectation and variance of $X_i$ in the formula for the central limit theorem, which they say are both equal to 1.

In the central limit theorem, do you use the expectation and variance of the $X_i$ or $X = \sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i $? Why is the variance of $X_i$ = 1 in this case? And also, what is the variance of $X = \sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i $?

Comment: The answer below has hopefully addressed your query. I'd like to add that if you are interested, you can check out the Berry Esseen theorem if you'd like a more accurate estimate.

Comment: Actually the point of Berry-Esseen is to give bounds rather than a more accurate approximation.  In this case the sum of independent Poisson r.v.'s is Poisson, so you really don't need either CLT or Berry-Esseen.

Answer (score 3):

For a Poisson random variable, the variance is always equal to the mean.

In general, the variance of the sum of independent variables is equal to the sum of the variances of all the variables.

Comment: And you could add that the sum of independent Poisson random variables is a Poisson random variable

Comment: @Henry There is that. But in this case it's irrelevant, since we're told to use the central limit theorem, which I think means that we approximate $\frac1{20}\sum X_i$ as a normal variable. I could also strengthen my second paragraph from independent variables to variables with zero (pairwise) covariance.